# Multiple write from multiple process in Android Content provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-room

I know Android's ContentProvider is known for multiple write from multi-process/multi-thread without throwing lock exception. In multithreaded environment it might have synchronized the method using read-write lock. But what about multi process where multiple object will be created. Can any one let me internal working of ContenProvider.

Answer (score 2):

A [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) is a manifest declared component, it is instantiated by the OS and is tied to the main process (unless the attribute [`process`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element#proc) is specified differently). Therefore only a single instance of a declared `ContentProvider` is created during the life time of that application process. Other processes that wish to interact with it must go through the [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver) which in turn just communicate with that single provider created.

Note that when a provider is used from another process it is communicating via IPC (via [Binders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder) specifically), which means a provider's methods will be invoked in a `BinderThread` during an IPC call. There is a pool of binder threads so that there can be some concurrent communication with multiple application, meaning appropriate synchronization should be done.

In summary, content providers are safe for multi-process & multi-thread interactions because:

1. They are a Singleton.
2. Multi-thread safety is guarantee by the developer with appropriate synchronization of shared state.
3. Multi-process safety is guarantee by the ContentProvider.
4. The ContentProvider's definition has return types that are suitable for IPC interaction. (They are Parcelable, like [AssetFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html), or they are a [SQLiteCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html?hl=en) which is backed by allocated shared memory using [ashmem](https://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features#ashmem)).